# Keurig K-Duo Plus brews only half of the brew size selected; k-cup pod holder has a loose object

Tags: keurig

I recently bought a [Keurig K-Duo Plus](https://www.keurig.com/Home-Coffee-Makers/K-Duo-Plus%E2%84%A2-Single-Serve-%26-Carafe-Coffee-Maker/p/K-Duo-Plus-Single-Serve-Carafe-Coffee-Maker:Matte%20Black_color). From time to time, when brewing from a k-cup, the brewer only brews half of the brew size selected - e.g., if I choose 8oz/10oz, it only brews like 4oz/5oz. This issue happens quite infrequently so it hasn't bothered me too much - but when I did some googling into why it is caused and what is the solution, I saw some suggestions to see if the k-cup pod holder is clogged. When I opened the pod holder, I saw a loose pin that was lying right under where the k-cup goes.

Does anyone know what this pin is, and where it goes / what its purpose is? Is this having been just sitting there loose, in the k-cup holder, something I should worry about? It was not obvious where the pin should have been, and it looks like the pin was coated in black color but lost some of that coating and shows a chrome-colored inside. Please pardon the grainy image, I wanted to add a k-cup for scale so the pin's size is apparent.

FWIW, I took the pin out and brewed a cup without any k-cups, it did brew the full brew size I selected.

[image]

Comment: Your problem isn't unique.  [Keurig K-Duo Coffee Maker Single Serve K-Cup HOW TO OPEN UP & SEE IF YOU CAN FIX IT Model K5100 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oo18XZQpXXY&t=3s&ab_channel=JustADadVideos) mentions the cup-size problem twice (5:40 and 7:40), but doesn't have a fix for it.